# Lorentz Force and Circular motion - What is the magnetic field causing the movement?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, charge

I am given this problem:

> A particle with mass $m$ and positive charge $q$ is moving in the following path on the $x$-$y$ plane. It's path consists of semicircles as shown below. The particle's velocity at the origin is $V_0$ in the $\hat y$ direction.
> What is the magnetic field causing this movement?

[image]

My thought was using the Lorentz force :
$F=q(V\times B)$, from this I know that the magnetic field is in the $\hat z$ direction,
and using circular motion:
$F=ma$, $a=\frac{V^2}R$.

But this is not the classic circular motion.

Comment: The magnetic field is not constant in space. It has different values in different locations.

Comment: Hint: think of the direction of rotation in each semicircle.

Comment: Where does the y/|y| come from?

Answer (score 1):

The magnetic field changes its direction when it crosses the x-axis. As you said, one can use the formula 
$$qvB=\frac{ mv²}{r}$$
For one side (say +y side) the magnetic field must be along the +z-axis. When the particle crosses the x-axis after completing a semicircle the magnetic field has same magnitude but reverses sign. Hence one can write 
$$ B= \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} - \frac{mv}{qr} & \quad y < 0 \\\frac{mv}{qr} & \quad y > 0 \end{array} \right. $$
Where the magnetic field is along the z-axis.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There are two different, opposite and with the same magnitude magnetic fields on upper and lower half-spaces.